# Implode values from array with NULL or empty values cause unexpected output

Tags: php, implode

I am trying to get the following output:

```
string1, string2, string3
```

Those values comes from `$var1`, `$var2` and `$var3` but they can be `NULL` at some point and here is where my problem is.

So far this is what I have:

```
$arr = array(
    $var1 !== null ? $var1 : '',
    $var2 !== null ? $var2 : '',
    $var3 !== null ? $var3 : '',
);

echo $arr !== '' ? implode(', ', $arr) : '-';
```

This are the test I've run:

```
input: array('string1', 'string2', 'string3')
output: string1, string2, string3

input: array('string1', 'string2')
output: string1, string2

input: array('', '', '')
output: , ,

input: array(null, null, null)
output: , ,
```

As you may notice if values are coming everything work as I want, if values are coming `NULL` then I am getting `, ,` when I what I want is just a `-`.

I have tried to find whether the array contains empty values or not using this code:

```
$cnt = count($arr) !== count(array_filter($arr, "strlen"));
echo $cnt;
```

Then I've run the following test:

```
input: array('string1', 'string2', 'string3')
output: 3

input: array('string1', 'string2')
output: 2

input: array('', '', '')
output: 1

input: array(null, null, null)
output: 1
```

What I am missing or doing wrong here? How I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you want `-` as the result or do you want `-, -, -`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver your answer is right, I will accept that one although both were helpful hard decision for the voting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the array before implode and if the imploded array is an empty string assign `-`, otherwise assign the imploded array:

```
$result = implode(', ', array_filter($arr)) ?: '-';
```

For PHP < 5.3.0 not supporting `?:` then:

```
$result = ($s = implode(', ', array_filter($arr))) ? $s : '-';
```

Comment: Ups, that last one for *older version* isn't working. I am using PHP 5.3.10 (don't kill me isn't me, is company rules) in development server.

Comment: Those should both work for 5.3.  Do you get an error?

Comment: No, I get `-` for all of them, even if values are coming. Both? You mean the first one should work as well? The problem is I am developing in a Docker container using PHP 5.5.9 but the  development server has PHP 5.3.10 so nvm I will make a few test and I will be back if they aren't working

Answer (score 3):

If you want `-`, then this is wrong:

```
echo $arr !== '' ? implode(', ', $arr) : '-';
     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

An array is not a string, and if you compare an array to a string, the array gets cast to a string, and turns into the literal word `Array`. That means you're doing

```
echo 'Array' !== '' ? ...
```

and of course, those aren't equal and you end up going down the `implode` path.

You have to test the individual values of the array for null, and then decide what to do. And note that `array_count_values()` won't work here - it can only count string/integer values. `null` as a value isn't countable.

```
php > $arr = array(null, null);
php > var_dump(array_count_values($arr));
PHP Warning:  array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values! in php shell code on line 1
PHP Warning:  array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values! in php shell code on line 1
array(0) {
}
```

So you have to do it the hard way:

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (is_null($value)) { $cnt++; }
}
if ($cnt == count($arr)) {
   ... array is all nulls
}
```